# The difference between events and conversions

Tags: firebase, events, firebase-analytics

I am using firebase and I really don't get the difference between events and conversions sections in the Firebase analytics?
Why should I decide that some event to be a conversion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A conversion event is an event that is considered super-special in your app -- it's the subset of events that you care most about.

When you label an event as a conversion event, a few things happen:

1. When a user triggers this event, of your analytics data on the device is flushed and sent immediately to Analytics
2. Analytics will try to match up these conversion events to the ad networks that brought these users to your app in the first place, so you can better figure out which ad networks are bringing you users that you care about.
3. Depending on how you've got Analytics set up, it might also send postbacks to these ad networks to let them know they've been successful in bringing you the right kind of user.
4. These events can be used as goals in Firebase Predictions

As a general rule, you want these to be events that don't happen too often, but are ones that indicate you've gotten a user who's important to you. Things like making a purchase, sharing the app with their friends, completing your initial tutorial, signing up for an account, and so on are all good events to label as conversion events.

Comment: my case falls on our last paragraph, which is if user completes a lesson, I want it to make a conversion. However, my app doesn't have ads, is it still considered as conversion? Because you mentioned in your item 2 about ads...